# How to remove sentences/phrases of a certain length from a list?

Tags: python, string, phrase

So this is a smaller version of my sentences/phrase list:

```
search = ['More than words', 'this way', 'go round', 'the same', 'end With', 'be sure', 'care for', 'see you in hell', 'see you', 'according to', 'they say', 'to go', 'stay with', 'Golf pro', 'Country Club']
```

What I would like to do is remove any terms that are more or less than 2 words in length. I basically just want another list with all 2 word terms. Is there a way to do this in Python? From my searching, I have only managed to find how to erase words of a certain number of characters and not entire phrases.

Comment: Just to be clear - you want to turn this into two separate lists. The first should contain all 2 word phrases, and the second should contain all the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get 2 word phrases using this:

```py
ans = list(filter(lambda s: len(s.split()) == 2, search))
```

Another way is using list comprehension:

```py
ans = [w for w in search if len(w.split()) == 2]
```

---

As OP asked for removing duplicates in comment, adding it here:

```py
ans = list(set(filter(lambda s: len(s.split()) == 2, search)))
```

Comment: I really recomend using the first solution, since `filter` was invented in this scope. Nice answer, +1

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to do. I'm not sure if I should ask a new question or not, but I also want to know how to remove duplicates. Does anyone know, and is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You can use set and then convert back to list again. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you take a simple approach and say every word must be separated by a space, then any two-word strings will only have 1 space character, three-word strings have 2 space characters, and so on (general rule, an n-word string has (n-1) spaces).

You can just break the two lists up like this (if you want one with strings <= two words, and one with strings > 2 words):

```py
twoWords = []
moreThanTwo = []

for s in search:
    if s.count(" ") == 1:
        twoWords.append(s)
    else
        moreThanTwo.append(s)
```

Or to simplify with a lambda expression and just extract a single list of all two-word strings:

```py
twoWords = list(filter(lambda s: s.count(" ") == 1, search))
```

Comment: Isn't the split solution more flexible on the grounds that the word separation can be any amount of whitespace? This solution will only work if the separation is exactly one space

Comment: Yes, but I have not seen an example of a sentence with more than one space separating words. And this matches OP's requirements perfectly (i.e. if this is a sample/test data set there is no reason for it to fail).

Answer (score -1):

As you want to get a new list with a list of words of length equal to 2, use list comprehension

```
new_list = [sentence for sentence in search if len(sentence.split(' ')) == 2]
```